# How can i show labels on a single bar graph depecting its value in flex for column chart?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-charts

**Please check this link**
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_displayingdata_07.html#332805

here the thing is it is showing labelposition on all 3 column chart(column series)
(from link.. jan :2000,feb:1000,march:1500)

but instead of showing in all months i want the value to be displayed only on **march**

how can i do it?
need help

Answer (score 2):

Create an itemrenderer(Implement IDataRenderer), and in set data method, write the condition for March month.